# Importing ons from 'onsenui/esm' gives an error

Tags: javascript, webpack, onsen-ui

I'm creating an app using pure JavaScript and Onsen UI
But, I got this error when tried to import the Onsen UI package (I'm using webpack)

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/onsenui/esm/ons/internal/animator-factory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-runtime/helpers/typeof' in 'D:\Documents\Pelajaran\Web\SIM RS Web Test 2\node_modules\onsenui\esm\ons\internal'
 @ ./node_modules/onsenui/esm/ons/internal/animator-factory.js 1:0-51 118:61-68
 @ ./node_modules/onsenui/esm/ons/internal/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/onsenui/esm/ons/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/onsenui/esm/index.js
 @ ./docs/js/app.js
```

Here's the code:

```
import ons from 'onsenui/esm'
```

But, for some reason, it won't give an error if you load all the components:

```
import ons from 'onsenui'
```

Do I have to install that `babel-runtime/helper` package?
Because the [docs](https://onsen.io/v2/guide/appsize.html#es-modules) says:

> there is no need to use any transpiler/compiler like Babel or Buble.

and

> Make sure you import `ons` from `onsenui/esm`, not from `onsenui`. Otherwise, every element will be directly included.

EDIT:
Here's the result of the bundle analyzer:
[image: Result of bundle analyzer]

Comment: I guess it will be treeshaked when you do a production build and include only what it needs from `onsenui`. You can use the `webpack-bundle-analyzer` to check the build outcome.
Can you check that?

Comment: It could be that OnsenUI uses Babel internally (you can see that the error happens in a JS file from a directory called "internal"). You're probably not supposed to load `onsenui/esm` yourself (unless specified in the documentation) and if you load an intended entry point, it might handle everything.

Comment: @rid the documentation says this: Make sure you import `ons` from `onsenui/esm`, not from `onsenui`. Otherwise, every element will be directly included.

Comment: @Legends I posted the analyzer result

Comment: @ErickChristian Can't see how big it is? You have to compare the full `onsenui` with the build outcome. Is it the same? Do u run in production mode?

Comment: @Legends so what do you mean is that I have to compare the onsenui package with the production build? But, again, the documentation says this: `Because, in this way, we do not relay on tree shaking algorithms.`

Comment: I would ask the `onsenui` team what the following means:

`ons.notification utilities rely on ons-alert-dialog and ons-toast, so make sure these elements are imported once before calling ons.notification.`

Usually a component must know its dependencies, a user should not be responsible for a components dependencies.

You better open an issue in their github repo or someone else here can help you.
--
Yes, you can compare the original bundle with the output bundle, if it is the same size then it is not treeshaked.